# Get YouTube video's view count in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, youtube

Is there anyway to write up a Sheets in Google Drive such that a cell will have the current (or as close to current as possible) number of views that video has received?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j6RsJmelphk","//div[@class='watch-view-count']")
```

which should return something like 97,000 (views for a Colin Farrell - Road to Hell video).

Comment: I started out trying this but I didn't have quotes around the class name so I was constantly getting an error.